# How can a SignalR client detect logout?

Tags: signalr

NB: this question is about SignalR ***authentication*** events, not ***transport*** events, which I already have covered.

Scenario: I have my SignalR application open in 2 tabs. In one, I log out. In the other, my SignalR connection appears to stay connected, but no response is returned to requests sent through the hub. How can I detect this scenario? I'm already detecting errors, reconnect and disconnect events, but it doesn't seem to correspond to any state change at all. This feels like a relatively common scenario but I can't seem to find any documentation about it.

Comment: So you want to detect if one of the tabs (html/javascript context?) was closed?

Comment: No, that's just a convenient way of triggering the logout issue. I want to detect a logout of any kind - maybe an auth cookie has expired, maybe the user has used some "log out all sessions" functionality like gmail has - the key thing is to detect that SignalR will no longer actually respond to requests

Comment: So the 2 opened tabs scenario: you log out from one tab and you want the other to log out as well?

Comment: Yes - but more precisely, that an existing SignalR connection in the other tab can become notified that *it's connection* has been logged out. Obviously the other tab will have become logged out already (i.e. they share cookies), but by default an active SignalR connection will enter a 'zombie' state where the server no longer responds to new requests but no error is raised. I want either an error or an event so I know the connection is essentially dead.

Comment: When you call log out you trigger a 'loggedOut' client method? I've done that a couple of times before...

Comment: I looked into that but couldn't find a good implementation. If the client calls the method, it doesn't notify other clients that share the logged-out session (e.g. other tabs); if the server calls the method, you have to 1) somehow access the live instance of the SignalR hub on the server, which they make hard to do nicely, and 2) you have to know what the SignalR ConnectionId(s?) of that client's session is, in order to identify which connections to send that message over. My quick attempt would sometimes kill connections for the same user in a different session (i.e. a different browser).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, SignalR genuinely doesn't know you've been logged out, so there doesn't seem to be any nice way to do this. I've now implemented a separate http endpoint "IsLoggedIn" that returns true or false, and I poll that via Ajax to work out when the user becomes logged out, but there **must** be a better way...